# Carets stop hyperlinks working.

Tags: support, markdown, formatting, hyperlinks

The caret symbol, ^, stops hyperlinks working, a phenomenon usually seen in links to Wolfram Alpha.

The [description](hyperlink) form:
[this works](http://wolframalpha.com/input/i=3x+2x),  produced by [this works](http://wolframalpha.com/input/i=3x+2x)
this doesn't,  produced by [this doesn't](http://wolframalpha.com/input/i=3^x+2x)

The HTML anchor form:
[this works](http://wolframalpha.com/input/i=ex+2x), produced by <a href="http://wolframalpha.com/input/i=ex+2x">this works</a>
this doesn't, produced by <a href="http://wolframalpha.com/input/i=e^x+2x">this doesn't</a>

Can anything be done to fix it, or a work-around found?

Comment: This question [Links / URLs containing special characters are not recognized by markdown](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/520/links-urls-containing-special-characters-are-not-recognized-by-markdown) is very similar.

Answer (score 7):

You can replace the `^` with the URL-encoded form `%5E`, e.g:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5Ex
```

instead of

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3^Ex
```

which will work like

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5Ex

If you use the link button of the editor, such characters will be automatically escaped. If you format your links manually, you have to escape them yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @Mad,  it seems that URL encoding is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

If, for any reason (e.g. you want to use it [in a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-do-you-cite-a-reference-in-a-comment) or in chat, or you simply prefer `[text](link)` syntax), you want to add [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) manually, you can find many online tools for that, e.g. this [url encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Example with Wolframalpha:

- Suppose I have link `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r^2-1<z^2<r^2`.
- I put the `r^2-1<z^2<r^2` part into encoder and I click on Encode.
- I get `r%5E2-1%3Cz%5E2%3Cr%5E2`.
- Now I can make a new link `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%5E2-1%3Cz%5E2%3Cr%5E2` which [works fine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%5E2-1%3Cz%5E2%3Cr%5E2).

Test: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%5E2-1%3Cz%5E2%3Cr%5E2

Comment: Thanks, @Martin, it seems that URL encoding is the way to go.